# Replacing few zeros of a dataframe with difference between two previous columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to execute:

```
df['C'] = df['C'].replace(0, lambda x: pd.Timedelta(x['B']-x['A']).days)
```

which is to replace all instances of zeros in column 'C' of dataframe 'df' with difference between column 'B' and 'A' which are of type datetime64. I want the result 'C' to be in days. Here is the snap of result after the above execution:
[image: dataframe after execution]

I am getting the column C values likes this. Instead i should get only the days which is the difference between the first two. What I am doin wrong?
(note: I don't want to do df['C'] = df['B'] - df['A'] because i want to replace only zeros, not existing non-zeros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select columns by mask in [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) and set days created by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html):

```
df.loc[df['C'] == 0, 'C'] = (df['B']-df['A']).dt.days
```

Comment: working for me! However, can you please explain how it is a selective operation rather than on a whole column? Because, when i tried pd.Timedelta(df['B']-df['A']).days , it use to throw an error